# Array of hashes - Nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have reorganized my input log data to below structure and trying to export as a excel spreadsheet. I'm facing below issue while pushing values to excel sheet and I have checked array for any nil class but the result is false and I'm not sure where is the issue.

```
final = [ {:server=>"new_US_dof1_new"}
{:name=>"OLAUS51", :data=>{"HAL"=>"6.93817139", "CCN_RESP"=>".035400391", "PA_RESP"=>".032287598", "PE_RESP"=>".000610352"}}
{:name=>"OLAUS10", :data=>{"HAL"=>"52.7266846", "CFG_RESP"=>"15.9489746"}}
{:name=>"IdofQA03", :data=>{"PA_RESP"=>".096374512"}}
{:name=>"QEMDB", :data=>{"HAL"=>"22.2698975", "PA_RESP"=>"11.7857666", "CCN_RESP"=>".229125977", "PE_RESP"=>".007202148"}}
{:name=>"OLAUS64", :data=>{"CCN_RESP"=>".757202148"}}
{:name=>"IISCR70", :data=>{}}
{:name=>"IQDV500", :data=>{}}
{:name=>"OLAUS80", :data=>{"PA_RESP"=>"10.5393066", "HAL"=>"4.73620605", "CCN_RESP"=>".023864746", "PE_RESP"=>".003723145", "OPENREPORTS"=>".001708984", "REPORT_RESP"=>".001281738"}}

{:server=>"new_US_dof2_new"}
{:name=>"IBDVHAL", :data=>{"HAL"=>"1.81048584", "FM_RESP"=>".001098633"}}
{:name=>"DEVSITEP", :data=>{"HAL"=>".088012695", "PE_RESP"=>".000610352"}}
{:name=>"OLAUS87", :data=>{"CFG_RESP"=>"1.57061768", "HAL"=>".47253418", "PA_RESP"=>".011962891", "PE_RESP"=>".007202148"}}

same format for other servers]
```

**Error**:

```
in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from excel.rb:34:in `each'
        from excel.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/axlsx-2.0.1/lib/axlsx/workbook/workbook.rb:262:in `add_worksheet'
```

I'm trying to format the data in excel sheet of below format

```
SERVER               NAME         DATA         GB

new_US_dof1_new"     OLAUS51      HAL          6.93817139
                                  CCN_RESP     .035400391
                                  PA_RESP      .032287598
                                  PE_RESP      000610352

                     OLAUS10      HAL           52.7266846
                                  CFG_RESP      15.9489746       

Likewise for other NAME & SERVER
```

The code I've come up with

```
require 'csv'
require 'axlsx'

final = []
current = -1

str = File.read("combined.log")
str.each_line do |line|
  line.strip!
  next if line.empty?
  next if line.include?('selected') || line.include?('IN_GB')
  next if ['-','='].include? line[0]
  parts = line.split ' '
   if parts.size == 1 and line.start_with?('size')
    final[current += 1] = {server: line.strip}
    next
  elsif parts.size == 1 and parts = /^(?!.*size_).*$/
    final[current += 1] = {name: line, data: {}}
    next
  end

  parts.each_cons(2) do |key, value|
    final[current][:data][key] = value 
    end
end

#puts final

p = Axlsx::Package.new

wb = p.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["SERVER", "NAME", "DATA", "GB]"]
    final.each do |val|
      sheet << [ val[:server], val[:name] ]
      val[:data].each do |k, v|
       sheet << ["", "", k, v]
      end
    end
end

p.serialize 'server.xlsx'
```

Posting the portion of the log file for reference:

```
---- db name ----
new_US_dof1_new

OLAUS51


RESP                    IN_GB
------------------------------ ----------
HAL                6.93817139
CCN_RESP               .035400391
PA_RESP            .032287598
PE_RESP            .000610352


=========================================


---- db name ----


OLAUS10


RESP                    IN_GB
------------------------------ ----------
HAL                52.7266846
CFG_RESP               15.9489746
CCN_RESP               .401794434
PA_RESP            .346679688
PE_RESP            .008056641


=========================================
I"m skipping the values for server 1 & proceeding to server 2 values for better readability 

---- db name ----
new_US_dof2_new

IBDVHAL

RESP                    IN_GB
------------------------------ ----------
HAL                1.81048584
FM_RESP           .001098633

=========================================


---- db name ----

DEVSITEP

RESP                    IN_GB
------------------------------ ----------
HAL                088012695
FM_RESP           .000610352

and so on for other server and values
```

Comment: I am unsure about your `final` var.  Its just one entry in that array. Don't know if this is intended.  Have you used `binding.pry` to inspect every that that it returns something expected?

Comment: There's a lot going on there... The error point to line `34`. Is that `final.each do |val|`? What is `final` at that point in the code? What is `val[:data]`? I suspect that in some cases it's `nil`, since you don't set it here:`final[current += 1] = {server: line.strip}`

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input log data?

Comment: However, this is the sort of question where I'm very hesitant to propose a "fix" - since the right answer is significantly redesign that algorithm. The code is complex and procedural; it's very hard to keep track of what variables are flying around - which is what lead you to this bug in the first place. At a first step, why don't you move `File.read("combined.log").each_line { ... }` into its own method, and give it a well-defined expected return value, which you can test in isolation?

Comment: @Leo: I have edited the question with the sample log inputs, thank you

Comment: @TomLord : final is an array holding the entire contents of the processed logs in the aforementioned format.
val[:data] is to access the hash `:data=>{"HAL"=>"6.93817139", "CCN_RESP"=>".035400391", "PA_RESP"=>".032287598", "PE_RESP"=>".000610352"}}` 

like that access for other data too

With my initial starting knowledge in RUby I've come with this data structure .. It would be extremely helpful if you could guide & hopefully give a fix :) to a Ruby learner like me, Thanks much for your time..

Comment: @DennyMueller : Thanks for your time here.. final is an array holding the values as I've posted in the question.. The value is huge hence cannot post the entire content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

That means error happens inside block from line 34(2 levels). So, `val[:data].each do |k, v|`. Your first hash from `final` array is `{:server=>"new_US_dof1_new"}` that haven't key `:data`.

```
final.each_with_object([]) do |val, line|
  if line.empty?
    line << val.key?(:server) ? val[:server] : ''
    next if val.key?(:server)
  end
  line << val[:name]

  val[:data].each do |k, v|
    line << k << v
    sheet << line.clone
    line.clear
    line << '' << ''
  end
  line.clear
end
```

Comment: So should I do like `final[current += 1] = {server: line.strip, data: {}}` instead of `final[current += 1] = {server: line.strip}` but again it adds an empty line to my excel sheet as empty {}is getting printed for every server detail.

Thanks a lot for your input..

Comment: You're awesome !! what is the diff b/n (:server) & [:server].. sorry If its really silly :(

Comment: Ahh I love how every excel generation that I came across in my career (including my own ones) looks like a minefield.